# Alternative to spinlock

Tags: java, user-interface, synchronization, spinlock

I am using the following spinlock approach:

```
while(!hasPerformedAction()){
    //wait for the user to perform the action
    //can add timer here too
}

setHasPerformedAction(false);

return getActionPerfomed();
```

this basically waits for a user to perform an action and then returns it. Currently something requests an answer from the user before continuing, this is why I wait until input is received. However I was wondering if this is inefficient and if we are waiting for a while (i.e. <= 30 secs) will it slow down the pc that is running this app. Are there any other alternatives using this approach i.e. locks, semaphores if so what is the syntax?

Thanks,

Aly

Comment: Where is the user performing the action? On the command line, in a GUI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, not only is this inefficient, it is not even guaranteed to work, since there is no "happens-before" edge in the code that you are showing. To create a [happens-before edge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) you need to do one of:

1. Access a volatile variable
2. Synchronise on a shared resource
3. Use a concurrent utils lock.

As mentioned in another comment, the *easiest* solution, is simply to ensure that your flag is a volatile variable, and simply throw a short sleep in your loop.

However, the best thing to do would be to synchronize/wait/notify on a shared variable.

The methods that you need to read up on are [wait](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) and [notify](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()). For a better description on how to use these, read [this article](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/wait_notify_how_to.shtml). An example code snippet is shown below;

**Thread 1**

```
Object shared = new Object();
startThread2(shared);
synchronized (shared) {
  while (taskNotDone())
    shared.wait();
}
```

**Thread 2**

```
// shared was saved at the start of the thread
// do some stuff
markTaskAsDone();
synchronized (shared) {
  shared.notify();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, The shared variable in this case is a boolean, and we cannot synchronize on a volatile boolean so I'm still a bit stuck

Comment: @Aly: You can either use a different variable as a second piece of shared state, use an AtomicBoolean (as opposed to bool) or simply insert a sleep into your loop, since if the boolean is volatile, then it is threadSafe.

Comment: This is not really a spinlock - it's a regular lock. The moment thread 1 calls wait - it is no longer schedulable so it will be switched out in favor of a thread that is schedulable. So anything thread 1 has in the CPU's cache is gone. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PaulWagland You should clarify that 1, 2 and 3 are either/or.

Comment: @quixver indeed this is not a spin lock, this is an alternative, and arguably a better one for the exact reason that you mention.

Answer (score 2):

What you've written is called busy looping, which you should never do.

You may want to keep doing that, but at least sleep a bit as to not be busy looping, which still wouldn't be that great:

```
while( !hasPerformedAction() ) {
    (sleep a bit here)
}
```

Another way to do it would to enqueue the user actions on a blocking queue: then you could simply be using a *queue.take* and the queue implementation would take care of the issue for you.

And another way would be to use a callback to be notified of the user actions.

Comment: People look down on the simplistic "sleep a bit here" solution, but in practice a 1ms or 10ms `sleep()` drops the observed system load from 100% to close to 0%. The reason is that the app is spending most of its time sleeping: 1ms is a long time compared to the time taken to wake up, check a flag and go back to sleep. So while not elegant, this is a very pragmatic solution requiring minimal change.

Comment: Having said that, *all* the other solutions offered here are more elegant, more efficient, more self-documenting, more robust... more better. ;)

Comment: @Carl: The problem is that this is actually not guaranteed to work, since there is no guarantee that the thread will see the update that the other thread has made. Most of the time it *happens* to work, but that cannot be relied upon.

Comment: @Paul: You're right, of course; that's why I pointed the OP to your mechanism using wait/notify. OldEnthusiast and I hearken back to times when Java multithreading was a lot simpler ;) . I'll now reluctantly retract my upvote for this solution in view of the danger of it not working.

Answer (score 2):

The java tutorials have a good lesson on concurrency in java:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

If you are going to be modifying UI from another thread, you will want to remember to do:

```
SwingUtils.invokeLater(actionToInvoke);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a <kbd>gui</kbd> in your tags, so I'll assume that the action is done in the GUI.

The "recommended" way to do this kind of thing is for the main thread to put itself to sleep (perhaps using `wait()`) and for the GUI action to `notify()` it back into wakefulness once the action has been performed.

Comment: would the code be something like if(!hasActionPerformed){wait();}
and in the action listener for the Gui component we set the actionPerformed and the call notifyAll()? Will errors be caused as the Gui stuff is done on the event dispatch thread?

Comment: To be honest, I've never tried this, and would approach it by trial & error starting with what you said. My preferred solution would be for the main thread to go away (i.e. run to completion) and the user action to start a thread that does the next processing step. Much cleaner.

Comment: I see Paul Wagland has explained wait/notify better, if you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are some classes for that in `java.util.concurrent.locks`. Have a look at Class `LockSupport`

Regards Mike