# threading issue with empty while loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I know how to do that correctly , but I want to know why this code run as I would to do ,** without any noted error ** , while if I remove  *Thread.sleep(100);* lines from the two while loop , the program enters infinite loop situation ?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
 interface Buffer
{
   // place int value into Buffer
   public void set( int value ) throws InterruptedException; 

   // obtain int value from Buffer
   public int get() throws InterruptedException; 
} // end interface Buffer


public class javaapplication32
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      // create new thread pool with two threads
      ExecutorService application = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

      // create CircularBuffer to store ints
      CircularBuffer sharedLocation = new CircularBuffer();

      // display the initial state of the CircularBuffer
      sharedLocation.displayState( "Initial State" );

      // execute the Producer and Consumer tasks
      application.execute( new Producer( sharedLocation ) );
      application.execute( new Consumer( sharedLocation ) );

      application.shutdown();
   } // end main
}
// Consumer.java
// Consumer's run method loops ten times reading a value from buffer.


 class Consumer implements Runnable 
{ 
   private final static Random generator = new Random();
   private final Buffer sharedLocation; // reference to shared object

   // constructor
   public Consumer( Buffer shared )
   {
      sharedLocation = shared;
   } // end Consumer constructor

   // read sharedLocation's value 10 times and sum the values
   public void run()
   {
      int sum = 0;

      for ( int count = 1; count <= 10; count++ ) 
      {
         // sleep 0 to 3 seconds, read value from buffer and add to sum
         try 
         {
            Thread.sleep( generator.nextInt( 3000 ) );    
            sum += sharedLocation.get();
         } // end try
         // if lines 26 or 27 get interrupted, print stack trace
         catch ( InterruptedException exception ) 
         {
            exception.printStackTrace();
         } // end catch
      } // end for

      System.out.printf( "\n%s %d\n%s\n", 
         "Consumer read values totaling", sum, "Terminating Consumer" );
   } // end method run
} // end class Consumer

 class Producer implements Runnable 
{
   private final static Random generator = new Random();
   private final Buffer sharedLocation; // reference to shared object

   // constructor
   public Producer( Buffer shared )
   {
      sharedLocation = shared;
   } // end Producer constructor

   // store values from 1 to 10 in sharedLocation
   public void run()
   {
      int sum = 0;

      for ( int count = 1; count <= 10; count++ ) 
      {  
         try // sleep 0 to 3 seconds, then place value in Buffer
         {
            Thread.sleep( generator.nextInt( 3000 ) ); // sleep thread   
            sharedLocation.set( count ); // set value in buffer
            sum += count; // increment sum of values
         } // end try
         // if lines 25 or 26 get interrupted, print stack trace
         catch ( InterruptedException exception ) 
         {
            exception.printStackTrace();
         } // end catch
      } // end for

      System.out.println( 
         "Producer done producing\nTerminating Producer" );
   } // end method run
} // end class Producer

 class CircularBuffer implements Buffer
{
   private final int[] buffer = { -1, -1, -1 }; // shared buffer

   private int occupiedCells = 0; // count number of buffers used
   private int writeIndex = 0; // index of next element to write to
   private int readIndex = 0; // index of next element to read

   // place value into buffer
   public  void set( int value ) throws InterruptedException
   {
      // wait until buffer has space avaialble, then write value;
      // while no empty locations, place thread in waiting state
      while (  occupiedCells == buffer.length) 
      {
        Thread.sleep(100);
      } // end while

      buffer[ writeIndex ] = value; // set new buffer value

      // update circular write index
      writeIndex = ( writeIndex + 1 ) % buffer.length;

      ++occupiedCells; // one more buffer cell is full
      displayState( "Producer writes " + value );
     // notifyAll(); // notify threads waiting to read from buffer
   } // end method set

   // return value from buffer
   public  int get() throws InterruptedException
   {
      // wait until buffer has data, then read value;
      // while no data to read, place thread in waiting state
      while (occupiedCells == 0 ) 
      { 
      **Thread.sleep(100);**
      } // end while

      int readValue = buffer[ readIndex ]; // read value from buffer

      // update circular read index
      readIndex = ( readIndex + 1 ) % buffer.length;

      --occupiedCells; // one fewer buffer cells are occupied
      displayState( "Consumer reads " + readValue );
   //   notifyAll(); // notify threads waiting to write to buffer

      return readValue;
   } // end method get

   // display current operation and buffer state
   public void displayState( String operation )
   {
      // output operation and number of occupied buffer cells
      System.out.printf( "%s%s%d)\n%s", operation, 
         " (buffer cells occupied: ", occupiedCells, "buffer cells:  " );

      for ( int value : buffer )
         System.out.printf( " %2d  ", value ); // output values in buffer

      System.out.print( "\n               " );

      for ( int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++ )
         System.out.print( "---- " );

      System.out.print( "\n               " );

      for ( int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++ )
      {
         if ( i == writeIndex && i == readIndex )
            System.out.print( " WR" ); // both write and read index
         else if ( i == writeIndex )
            System.out.print( " W   " ); // just write index
         else if ( i == readIndex )
            System.out.print( "  R  " ); // just read index
         else
            System.out.print( "     " ); // neither index
      } // end for

      System.out.println( "\n" );
   } // end method displayState
}
```

my question is not how to do that correctly , but it's

- if I  run this code above I gain what I want , try it to know how it's work
- but if I remove   **Thread.sleep(100);** form both while loop , the code is not run as I ran it with  **Thread.sleep(100);** in the previous case .

Comment: Your code is in a finite loop either way, it's just that the processor only bothers checking the condition ten times a second as opposed to the many thousand it tries without being slept.

Comment: Unrelated, but still - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: the approach you have selected is very bad, it's awful! why do you check the a variable in a while again and again, you need to [synchronize](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#synctr) threads with each other

Comment: why downvoting? let him learn... +1 nice question

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach nice point, I'll do it as you did +1,for the Java

Comment: ignore of the better solution by using wait or synchronized , 
why with sleep it's run correctly and without it run incorrectly ?

Comment: Hey did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

The `Thread.sleep`s serve to reduce unnecessary CPU usage. On single core systems not sleeping may starve the other threads of CPU time, and so it may take a very long time to get out of the spinlock. In any case, [look into using `wait()` and `notify()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173309/alternative-to-spinlock) instead of implementing your own spinlock.

Comment: +1 you've beaten me in time and quality :D

Comment: Also could suggest using the concurrency package: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: @Jyro117 Looks like he already is, to some degree. :)

Comment: Well I meant for locks :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe its infinite but its going in this direction. Look about the used processor capacity. As long as both threads run in the same process, the share the same processor core. I would bet that the checking will gain all resources...